# multilingual application in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an application in Windows Phone 7.0 and now I want to make it multilingual supporting both English and French languages.

Could anybody guide me through the approach I should follow for supporting it in multilingul.

Thanks 
SAM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended approach is to expose any `ResourceManager` instances as XAML `Resources` (via a wrapper class, since the resources are only available at runtime). You can then bind to the properties of the strongly typed ResourceManager in XAML.

Here is some documentation that might help:

- [How to: Build a Localized Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637520%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)
- [Globalization and Localization for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637522%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

And some other resources to help:

- [PhoneCommonStrings](https://github.com/richardszalay/phone-common-strings) contains strings commonly used in WP7 applications, localized to all available languages (disclaimer: I'm the author of the library)
- [BindableApplicationBar](http://nuget.org/packages/BindableApplicationBar) allows you to bind the text (and command) of your application bar buttons

Comment: Can the downvoter give an indication of what is wrong with my answer? My description of the approach is correct as per the MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [my blog](http://hopnet.mobi/website/Blog.aspx): I just wrote about this very subject a couple weeks ago. It gives you step-by-step instructions.

Basically:

1. Create the project
2. Edit the .csproj file in notepad to add the desired cultures to the  tag.
3. Select a neutral culture in the project's properties
4. Add Resources to the project in Solution Explorer
5. Create a class to access those resources
6. Add that class to the  tag of the App.xaml file
7. Put your strings into the Resources file
8. Bind to those strings using the resource binding in your xaml.
9. If using an ApplicationBar, you must do so in code, as it cannot be bound in xaml.
10. Create another resource file for each supported culture.
11. Create dll files for each supported language, so the title will be correct on the tile and program list.

Comment: Please post some more information here than just a link so that your answer will be useful even if/when your blog goes away.

Comment: Thanks for the down, smart guy.  Please show me how you would have answered this person's question without a link.  You can tell by looking at my rep that I'm new here, so instead of being a jerk, be helpful.

Comment: See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) and [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle/84345#84345) on meta. "Links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer."

Comment: @hopmedic - It's always a nice idea to give an overview of the answer, even if the meat of it is an external link. I've found a number of questions where the answers are just a broken link and it's very frustrating.

Comment: Oh the irony when you realize that the blog no longer exists. At least at that address.